# Spring calls twice the "main" method: causing Exception on second Admin SDK Server-side authentication

Tags: java, spring, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to integrate some Firebase features on our server-side, which uses Spring.

Apparently, Spring can decide to launch multiple times the `public static void main` (I'll call it "main" from now on) method. (Why?)

The problem is that Firebase needs our server to authenticate itself before being able to use some Admin SDK features (such as verifying the signature of an idToken). I thought this would usually go in the `main` method, but as it is, it is being called twice, which causes a `FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] already exist.` Exception.

I guess there are two solutions, so I'll ask two questions:

1. How do I prevent Spring from running the `main` multiple times? (Why does it even do that?)
2. How do I prevent the server-authentication to be called twice? (Maybe a simple `private static boolean` attribute will suffice, but I feel like there should be a better way to work around that.)

**EDIT**: It seems like the "boolean" approach doesn't even work. I'm guessing that Spring's second calls are asynchronous..?

**EDIT:**

Here is the `main()` code (the `authenticateServer()` method is ran twice before Spring is launched):

```
package hackqc18.Acclimate;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import hackqc18.Acclimate.authentication.VerifyToken;
import hackqc18.Acclimate.notifications.PushNotifServiceImpl;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling

public class AcclimateApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Nécessaire!
        authenticateServer();

        SpringApplication.run(AcclimateApplication.class, args);
    }


    /**
     * Utilisé pour démontrer comment utiliser certaines fonctionnalités.
     */
    private static void demonstrationTemplate() {

    // [ Exemple de PUSH NOTIFICATION vers 2 appareils ]
        ArrayList<String> listOfDevices = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfDevices.add("...");
        listOfDevices.add("...");
        PushNotifServiceImpl.sendPushNotification(listOfDevices,"Test","Backend SPAMMMMMMM!");
    // [ Fin de l'exemple de notifs ]


    // [ Exemple de vérification d'un "idToken" et extraction du UID ]
        String idToken = "...";
        String uID = VerifyToken.verifyIdToken(idToken);
        System.out.println("Identified uID: " + uID);
    // [ Fin de l'exemple ]


    // TODO: CETTE MÉTHODE NE FONCTIONNE TOUJOURS PAS !!
    // [ Exemple d'envoie d'une notif à un appareil ]
        String registrationToken = "...";
        PushNotifServiceImpl.sendThroughGoogle(registrationToken);
    // [ Fin de l'envoie ]
    }

    /**
     * Admin SDK API (Firebase) - nécessaire
     * Pour authentifier le serveur d'Acclimate au serveur de Firebase.
     * Permet d'utiliser les fonctionnalités de l'Admin SDK.
     */
    private static void authenticateServer() {

        try {
            // [ Obtenir l'instance de Firebase App pour utiliser Admin SDK ]
            FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("abc.json");

            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://bob.com/")
                    .build();

            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            // [ Fin de la validation du Admin SDK API ]
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // TODO: Juste là pour des fins de démonstration.
        demonstrationTemplate();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Adding some more code.

Here is `AppConfig.java` :

```
package hackqc18.Acclimate;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
//import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("hackqc18")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**");
    }
}
```

Here is `pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hackqc18</groupId>
    <artifactId>Acclimate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Acclimate</name>
    <description>Hackathon Québec 2018</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <geotools.version>18.1</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geojson</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.bedatadriven</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jts</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- Jeremi added Firebase Admin SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- Firebase Admin SDK-->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>derby</artifactId> -->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- >
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <-->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Here is `nbactions.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
    <action>
        <actionName>run</actionName>
        <packagings>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        </packagings>
        <goals>
            <goal>process-classes</goal>
            <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <properties>
            <exec.args>-classpath %classpath hackqc18.Acclimate.AcclimateApplication</exec.args>
            <exec.executable>java</exec.executable>
        </properties>
    </action>
</actions>
```

**EDIT:** That's the message I get before Spring actually starts. My methods in `main()` are called once before this message, and once after this message. Then, Spring actually starts.

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-geojson\18.1\gt-geojson-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/gt-main-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/gt-api-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/jts-core-1.14.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/jdom-1.1.3.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/json-simple-1.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/gt-referencing-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/core-0.26.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/gt-metadata-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/jgridshift-1.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/GeographicLib-Java-1.44.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/commons-lang-2.6.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geojson/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-main\18.1\gt-main-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/gt-api-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/gt-referencing-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/core-0.26.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/gt-metadata-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/jgridshift-1.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/GeographicLib-Java-1.44.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/jts-core-1.14.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/jdom-1.1.3.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-main/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-api\18.1\gt-api-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/jts-core-1.14.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/gt-referencing-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/core-0.26.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/gt-metadata-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/jgridshift-1.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/GeographicLib-Java-1.44.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-api/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-referencing\18.1\gt-referencing-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/core-0.26.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/gt-metadata-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/jgridshift-1.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/GeographicLib-Java-1.44.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-referencing/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-metadata\18.1\gt-metadata-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-metadata/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-metadata/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-metadata/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-metadata/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-metadata/18.1/jts-core-1.14.0.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-opengis\18.1\gt-opengis-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-opengis/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-opengis/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-opengis/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\geotools\gt-geometry\18.1\gt-geometry-18.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/jsr-275-1.0-beta-2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/gt-main-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/gt-api-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/jts-core-1.14.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/jdom-1.1.3.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/gt-referencing-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/core-0.26.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/gt-metadata-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/gt-opengis-18.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/jgridshift-1.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/GeographicLib-Java-1.44.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/org/geotools/gt-geometry/18.1/jai_core-1.1.3.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-netty-shaded\1.10.1\grpc-netty-shaded-1.10.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/grpc-core-1.10.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/grpc-context-1.10.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/gson-2.7.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/opencensus-contrib-grpc-metrics-0.11.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/opencensus-api-0.11.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/guava-19.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository/io/grpc/grpc-netty-shaded/1.10.1/jsr305-3.0.0.jar
12:51:34.090 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
12:51:34.125 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/]
12:51:34.125 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/Users/PC/Documents/GitHub/acclimateServer/target/classes/]
2018-08-09 12:51:36.273 DEBUG 10984 --- [  restartedMain] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/PC/Documents/GitHub/acclimateServer/target/classes/]
```

Comment: "Apparently, Spring can decide to launch multiple times the public static void main (I'll call it "main" from now on) method. (Why?)" - Not really sure what you mean by this. Is your `main()` being called multiple times in a single launch? Unless you provide us with some code, it would be difficult for us to provide you with any suggestion. IMHO, spring only calls `main()` once and if you have classes that implement `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` and they are marked `@Component` and they are under scanned packages, their `run(...)` would be called once as well.

Comment: Added the code, plus a mini explication. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you have `spring-dev-tools` declared in your maven pom?

Comment: I created a very simple application having same structure as your code example and after running it, I found that the main was called only once. I also included `spring-boot-devtools` to reproduce the issue but there was no success. Probably you have not posted a minimum verifiable code. Please create a small sample application and post a github link so that we can have a look into it.

Comment: The repo is private, and I cannot give access to it. I've added some more code that might be relevant. I know next to nothing about Spring, and the person that has been integrating it has just started learning. She says she found **[an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/multiple-datasources/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/multipleds/Application.java)** of some methods being called despite not being in the `main`, which might be a clue?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic I can't seem to find it in the `pom.xml` file. Why?

Comment: Found `devtools` instead of `dev-tools`. Read a bit about it, and it was indeed causing the Restart. I commented it, and now it doesn't restart anymore. Will keep on investigating (since it seems like Spring now exits with code 1, which is bad).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that the `devtools` was the cause of this weird behaviour. I simply removed this part of the `pom.xml` to solve the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```